# How to jump to next print page in C# PrintDocument method

Tags: c#, printing

I tried the below code ,

```
Private void button1_click(object sender, EvenArgs e)
{
      PrintDoument pd = new PrintDoument();
      pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDocument_PrintPage1);
      pd.Print();
}

Private void printDocument_PrintPage1(object sender, system.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
      e.Graphics.DrawString("Test 1",new Font("Arial",8,FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,50,500);
      e.Graphics.DrawString("Test 2",new Font("Arial",8,FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,50,1000);
      e.HasMorePages = true;

      e.Graphics.DrawString("Test 3",new Font("Arial",8,FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,50,2000);
      e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

I want to print "Test 3" String in next page,but it print only one page.Please show me a way to do this.

Comment: `e.HasMorePages = true;` After setting it to true you should leave the event. The value only works when leaving..

Comment: Please tell me how to leave the event?

Comment: like you leave any event: Either reach the last line or code a return. Make sure, when re-entering to know what you already have printed. A line index is usually used for that but there are many options..

Comment: `printDocument_PrintPage1` will be called again when the HasMorePages is set to true.  You will need a variable at the form scope that you can keep track what page you are on if you want to do something on that particular page.

Comment: @LaraTech thanks friend, it works. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue here is your PrintPage1 method.  That's not allowed.

You simply have a PrintPage method.  It will be called to print the first page and will continue to be called until it returns with E.HasMorePages = false;  In between each call the print engine will take care of actually printing the page and giving you a new page to draw on.

Also, unrelated to your question:  You are leaking Font objects here.  They have unmanaged resources, you must dispose of them.  Create them when you start printing, dispose of them when you're done.

Comment: `The fundamental issue here is your PrintPage1 method. That's not allowed.`  What are you trying to say here?  It's not clear what "not allowed" means.

Comment: @LarsTech He's trying to point it at a method to print the first page.  There's one method to print **all** pages (although that routine can call separate routines if you want.))

Comment: Still not clear to me.  The user is calling `pd.Print();` which will then call the `printDocument_PrintPage1` method.  That's all proper.  I don't see the "not allowed" part.

Comment: @LarsTech Perhaps "not allowed" isn't the right wording--he's trying to use it very differently than it's designed to work.  You provide a method that prints pages, not a method that prints page 1.